# program running through my if else after function call

Tags: c

I have a class assignment in C to make a simple calculator that performs three calculations. I haven't completed all of the functions yet but I am having a problem with my calcMenu function. When the function is called the program runs through all of the if else statements and unknown to me, performs only the else statement which is error checking. Than the function is run again which is intended but this time it does not run through all of the if else statements and allows the user to make a choice. I know I have done something really stupid but have been racking my brain for the last hour. If anyone has any pitty for me, than please point  me in the right direction. I know all the system calls will Irk some but this is a basic class and our instructor has told us to use them.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define pause system ("pause")
#define cls system ("cls")

//Prototype calculate functions here
void evenOrOdd(int userNumber);
void squareNum(int userNumber);
void cubeNum(int userNumber);
void calcMenu(int userNumber);

void main() {
    //Declare local variables here
int userNumber = 0;
printf("\t\t\tThe amazing three function caluculator\n\n\n");
printf("Please enter a whole number that you would like to calculate\n");
scanf("%d", &userNumber);


calcMenu(userNumber);
}



void calcMenu(int userNumber)
{
char calculateOption;
printf("\nWhat calculation would you like to perform with your number?\n\n");
printf("Press A.) to check if your number is even or odd.\n\n");
printf("Press B.) to calculate the square of your number.\n\n");
printf("Press C.) to calculate the cube of your number.\n\n");
printf("press D.) to exit the program.\n");
scanf("%c", &calculateOption);
calculateOption = toupper (calculateOption);



if (calculateOption == 'A')
{
    evenOrOdd(userNumber);
}
else if (calculateOption == 'B')
{
    squareNum(userNumber);
}
else if (calculateOption == 'C')
{
    cubeNum(userNumber);
}
else if (calculateOption == 'D')
{
    system("cls");
    printf("Thank You for using my amazing calculator.\n\n");
    system ("pause");
    system ("exit");
}
else
{
    printf("Please enter a valid choice");
    calcMenu(userNumber);
}


}


void evenOrOdd(int userNumber) {
userNumber = userNumber %2;
if (userNumber == 0)
{
    printf("Your number is even. \n");
}
else
{
    printf("Your number is odd. \n");
}

}
void squareNum(int userNumber) {

}
void cubeNum(int userNumber){

}
```

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger. It will help you immensely.

Comment: The function call `system ("exit");` doesn't really do what you expect it to. You are probably looking for the [`exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You can condense all those printf statements into one function to save the extra calls.

Next, you should probably indent your functions, I can't tell where one begins and another ends at a glance.

Third, don't use `system("pause")`, use `getchar()`.

Fourth, this is optional, you might want to turn those if statements into a switch statement.

**Now**, on to your question. First of all, instead of using `scanf("%c", &calculateOption)`, just use `getchar()` here too. In this case, I would write calcMenu() as this:

```
int calcMenu(int userNumber){
    printf("\nWhat calculation would you like to perform with your number?\n\n\
    Press A.) to check if your number is even or odd.\n\n\
    Press B.) to calculate the square of your number.\n\n\
    Press C.) to calculate the cube of your number.\n\n\
    Press D.) to exit the program.\n");

    switch(toupper(getchar())){
        case 'A':
            evenOrOdd(userNumber);
            break;
        case 'B':
            squareNum(userNumber);
            break;
        case 'C':
            cubeNum(userNumber);
            break;
        case 'D':
            system("cls"); //this is bad, really.
            printf("Thank You for using my amazing calculator.\n\n");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Please enter a valid choice: ");
            calcMenu(userNumber);
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, main should always return a value. `void main` is bad practice.

Disclaimer: The code isn't tested, you shouldn't copy/paste it anyways. I also don't know if you're being forced to use some things or not...

Comment: Thank you, I dont know why i did not think of using a switch statement first, much better than a if/else. I did use a getchar() in my last assignment in place of system pause. I will do that. Thanks

Comment: `void main` isn't only bad practice, it's actually "illegal" as the standard specifies that `main` _must_ return an `int`. @MichaelBrooks And while on the subject, in plain old C a function declaration with no arguments is actually declaring a function with unspecified arguments. If you want a function that takes no arguments, `main` included, you have to declare it with a `void` argument: `int main(void)`

Answer (score 2):

When you read input with `scanf` you have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to make the program continue. Your `scanf` call reads the single character from the input, but leaves the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key still in the input buffer, to be read next time you call `scanf`.

There is a very simple trick to solve that: Place a space in the `scanf` format string before or after the `"%c"`. This will make `scanf` skip whitespace.

```
scanf("%c ", &calculateOption);
```

If you stepped through the code with a debugger you would have easily seen that `calculateOption` would have been the newline character.

Comment: I practice using debugger in visual studio. That will hopefully prevent me from posting simple questions every time I have a road bump.